# windows CLI command won't run via IIS but does run via CLI

Tags: command-line, php, cmd.exe, windows-server-2008, imagemagick

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\magick" convert "G:\path\to\filename.pdf[1]" -colorspace RGB -geometry 800 "g:\path\to\temp\filename.png"
```

It runs great if I run it via `cmd` while I'm logged in but if I try to run it via IIS / PHP / [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) it doesn't work. I get the following error instead:

```
convert: no images defined `g:\path\to\temp\filename.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.
```

I've given Full Control permission to `g:\path\to\temp` to IUSR, IIS_USERS, ANONYMOUS LOGIN and Everyone. Nothing works.

I do `exec('echo %username%')` and see that the currently logged in user via IIS is `COMPUTER$` but that doesn't really help me.

edit:

I've given "Everyone" Full Control permission in `C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin` and `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16` and still get the same thing.

edit 2:

To whoever flagged my question as a duplicate of [Can't convert PDF into image, because of 'no images defined' error](https://superuser.com/q/819277/172193) ...  it is not. First, I am running Windows - not Linux - so obviously `which gs` is not going to work. Second, in my case, `convert` works just fine when I run it via cmd.exe. But when I try to run it via IIS / PHP / exec() it does not work. In the other question it didn't work at all. Period.

edit 3:

I also tried to create a new application pool with "LocalSystem" per https://stackoverflow.com/a/23046001/569976. Nothing.

Comment: Why does `\`g:\path\to\temp\filename.png'` start with a backtick?

Comment: And why does `"g:\path\to\temp\filename.png"\`` end with a backtick?

Comment: There is a backtick at the end of the first command in your post ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - goot catch on the backtick in the command I issued. I removed it but am getting the same error. I have no idea why it's in the output.

Comment: try run with  `-debug all`

Comment: @AdamSilenko - see http://pastebin.com/wWWvzSzc .

Comment: can you add debug from cmd? Did you give read permission to G:\path\to\filename.pdf[1]?

Comment: @AdamSilenko - debug from cmd is 343kb when I do `> log.txt 2>&1`. I'm gonna guess that's too big for pastebin. And yes - everything in G:\path\to has read permission. I've tried to give Full Control permission to Everyone in every relevant directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.09\bin`, `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16`, `g:\path\to\temp` and `g:\path\to`) and doing that should include the subdirectories.

Comment: give only first 150 lines...

Comment: @AdamSilenko - see http://pastebin.com/aQ85bTKV

Comment: Running by exec magick start as system and use system local settings (it use C:\Windows\Temp),  
check paths in `configure.xml` & `policy.xml`, try set constant path and permission for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by just installing WAMP. So IIS is running on port 80 / 443 and WAMP is running on port 81 / 444.