# Cannot draw with Imagemagick (no images defined)?

Tags: images, conversion, imagemagick

I have seen [Can't convert PDF into image, because of 'no images defined' error](https://superuser.com/questions/819277/cant-convert-pdf-into-image-because-of-no-images-defined-error) - but that seems related to PDF specifically.

Here I try to do something else - just to draw an image, using a command found in https://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#circles; I'm in a MSYS2 `bash` shell on Windows 10:

```
$ magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-11 Q16 x86_64 2020-09-04 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw flif fontconfig freetype gslib gvc heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf xml zlib

$ magick convert -size 300x300 -stroke SeaGreen -fill PaleGreen -strokewidth 2 -draw 'translate 50,30 circle 0,0 25,0' circle01.png
convert: no images defined `circle01.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3282.

$ magick convert -size 300x300 -stroke SeaGreen -fill PaleGreen -strokewidth 2 -draw 'translate 50,30 circle 0,0 25,0' circle01.png -debug all
2020-11-18T09:27:57+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.0.10 Configure convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/utility.c/ExpandFilenames/971/Configure
  Command line: convert {-size} {300x300} {-stroke} {SeaGreen} {-fill} {PaleGreen} {-strokewidth} {2} {-draw} {translate 50,30 circle 0,0 25,0} {circle01.png} {-debug} {all}
2020-11-18T09:27:57+00:00 0:00.003 0.000u 7.0.10 Policy convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/611/Policy
  Domain: Module; rights=Read; pattern="PNG" ...
2020-11-18T09:27:57+00:00 0:00.004 0.000u 7.0.10 Module convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/module.c/OpenModule/1278/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2020-11-18T09:27:57+00:00 0:00.004 0.000u 7.0.10 Module convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/547/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2020-11-18T09:27:57+00:00 0:00.025 0.000u 7.0.10 Module convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/module.c/OpenModule/1287/Module
  Opening module at path "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.10/modules-Q16HDRI/coders\png.la"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.122 0.047u 7.0.10 Module convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/module.c/OpenModule/1314/Module
  Method "RegisterPNGImage" in module "PNG" at address 00007FFD8EF21B80
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.122 0.047u 7.0.10 Module convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/module.c/OpenModule/1328/Module
  Method "UnregisterPNGImage" in module "PNG" at address 00007FFD8EF22070
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.140 0.047u 7.0.10 Policy convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/611/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="circle01.png" ...
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.140 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/share/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.140 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.10/config-Q16HDRIlocale.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/etc/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ImageMagick\locale.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:\msys64\home\user\.config\ImageMagick\locale.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Configure convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1206/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "C:/msys64/mingw64/share/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml" ...
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/share/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.10/config-Q16HDRIenglish.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/etc/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.141 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:/msys64/mingw64/share/doc/ImageMagick-7/english.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.142 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ImageMagick\english.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.142 0.047u 7.0.10 Locale convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/854/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "C:\msys64\home\user\.config\ImageMagick\english.xml"
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.142 0.047u 7.0.10 Configure convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1206/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "C:/msys64/mingw64/share/ImageMagick-7/english.xml" ...
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.145 0.047u 7.0.10 Exception convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496/Exception
  unable to open image 'circle01.png': No such file or directory
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.145 0.047u 7.0.10 Cache convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1042/Cache
  destroy
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.146 0.047u 7.0.10 Policy convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/611/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="circle01.png" ...
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.146 0.047u 7.0.10 Exception convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496/Exception
  unable to open image 'circle01.png': No such file or directory
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.146 0.047u 7.0.10 Cache convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickCore/cache.c/DestroyPixelCache/1042/Cache
  destroy
2020-11-18T09:27:58+00:00 0:00.146 0.047u 7.0.10 Exception convert[4620]: ../ImageMagick-7.0.10-11/MagickWand/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3279/Exception
   `all'
convert: unable to open image 'circle01.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496.
convert:  `all' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3279.
```

Strangely, if I create an empty file via `touch circle01.png`, Imagemagick tries to open it and fails - even if I want Imagemagick to *generate* this file?

How to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Eh, it seems I had forgotten to include `xc:` in my command; so the right command is:

```
magick convert -size 300x300 xc: -stroke SeaGreen -fill PaleGreen -strokewidth 2 -draw 'translate 50,30 circle 0,0 25,0' circle01.png
```

... and this one generates the file fine.